# Why won't this list of struct allow me to assign values to the field?

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5

```
Public Structure testStruct
    Dim blah as integer
    Dim foo as string
    Dim bar as double
End Structure

'in another file ....

Public Function blahFooBar() as Boolean
    Dim tStrList as List (Of testStruct) = new List (Of testStruct)

    For i as integer = 0 To 10
        tStrList.Add(new testStruct)
        tStrList.Item(i).blah = 1
        tStrList.Item(i).foo = "Why won't I work?"
        tStrList.Item(i).bar = 100.100

        'last 3 lines give me error below
    Next

    return True
End Function
```

The error I get is: Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.

Why?

Comment: Easy solution: Don't use a struct, use a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second the opinion to use a class rather than a struct.

The reason you are having difficulty is that your struct is a value type.  When you access the instance of the value type in the list, you get a *copy* of the value.  You are then attempting to change the value of the copy, which results in the error.  If you had used a class, then your code would have worked as written.

Answer (score 2):

try the following in your For loop:

```
Dim tmp As New testStruct()     
tmp.blah = 1
tmp.foo = "Why won't I work?"
tmp.bar = 100.100
tStrList.Add(tmp)
```

Looking into this I think it has something to do with the way .NET copies the struct when you access it via the List(of t).

More information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76435b93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the object first as

```
Dim X = New testStruct
```

and setting the properties on THAT  as in

```
testStruct.blah = "fiddlesticks"
```

BEFORE adding it to the list.

Comment: I was going to do that but structs don't work the same as classes. Meaning that all of the structs in the list would have been pointing to the same struct, not different ones.

Comment: Even with a *New* in the constructor?  Interesting. That's one for me to remember.

Comment: Using New will create a new instance of the struct.

Comment: That's what I thought.  But I think the lesson here is: avoid structs, use classes instead.